# I'm trying to add Weave Net addon to my kubernetese cluster, while the cluster is within a restricted network, and getting a time out error

Tags: linux, kubernetes, weave

I'm using following cmd to add add Weave Net addon to my newly configured kubernetese cluster( which is resides in a restricted network), have used proxy URLS during kubernetese installation.I'm getting following error when executing below command

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/releases/download/v2.8.1/weave-daemonset-k8s.yaml
```

**
Unable to connect to the server: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
**

Tried using wget to download the .yaml file and apply the same cmd, yet getting the same error. can some one suggest a work around for this?

Comment: Have you [enabled IP forwarding](https://acloudguru.com/hands-on-labs/setting-up-kubernetes-networking-with-weave-net) before installing the Weave net addon?

Comment: yes I have. Thanks for your reply, I have found the issue and got it resolved, The issue was, I was exporting proxy URLS before executing the above pod network adding command, which make the kubelet to seek pod network configs through proxy(as I believe - proxy already configured within docker to reach internet) , I opened a new terminal without executing the proxy export and it did the work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was, I was exporting proxy URLS before executing the above pod network adding command, which make the kubelet to seek pod network configs through proxy(as I believe.  proxies are already configured within docker to reach internet) , I opened a new terminal without executing the proxy export and it did the work.